# Isomorphism between two Ext-groups obtained from an exact sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

I don't understand a step in a proof in the book "Cohen-Macaulay Rings" by Winfried Bruns. It is in the proof of Proposition 3.1.10.

There we have a commutative ring $R$, an Ideal $J\subset R$ and an $R$-module $M$.
In the proof we obtain an exact sequence
$$ 
0\to M \to I^0\to I^1\to ...\to I^{n-1}\to C\to 0
$$ 
with all the $I^{i}$ injective modules. It is therefore clear that 
$$
\operatorname{Ext}^{i}_R(R/J,I^{i})=0 \quad \forall i>0.
$$
The author now states that we get an isomorphism 
$$
\operatorname{Ext}^{1}_R(R/J,C)\simeq \operatorname{Ext}^{n+1}_R(R/J,M).
$$
Can someone explain to me where this comes from? I know about existence of the long exact Ext-sequence when we have a short exact sequence and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

It is true if $n=1$: the exact sequence
$$ 0\longrightarrow M\longrightarrow I^0\longrightarrow C\longrightarrow 0 $$
yields the long exact sequence:
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Ext}{Ext}\cdots\longrightarrow\underset{\substack{\parallel\\0}}{\Ext^i(R/J,I^0)}\longrightarrow\Ext^i(R/J,C)\longrightarrow\Ext^{i+1}(R/J,M)\longrightarrow\underset{\substack{\parallel\\0}}{\Ext^{i+1}(R/J,I^0)}\longrightarrow\cdots$$

For the general case, proceed by induction on $n$:
$$\begin{matrix}
0\longrightarrow M\longrightarrow& I^0--\!\!&\!\!--\!\!&\!\!\longrightarrow&I^1&\longrightarrow\cdots\longrightarrow C\longrightarrow0\\
&\searrow&&\nearrow\\&&\!\!C'\!\\
&\;\qquad\nearrow\\
&0\end{matrix}$$